# Did I just buy an inverted front derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-front

I have a mtb and my derailleur is old, now that I removed it I see that is in tip top condition(I try to take very good care of my bike) but as I already had the new one, I decided to just go with the new one, and to my surprise, the cable anchor is... Upside down?

I mean, my derailleur was a generic chinese derailer and the anchor was on the top, and the one I bought is the shimano tz 500(https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney-tz500/FD-TZ500-DS6.html) and this thing has the anchor on the bottom(and the cable coming from my shimano break and shifter combo goes through the bottom of the bike)

Am I installing it wrong? Is there a trick to the installation or is that for a special kind of bike with the cable stops going from the top? I cannot set it up to actually move when I change gears in the shifter

Comment: FWIW, I once mistakenly bought a top pull front derailleur when my frame was only set up for bottom pull. The mechanic had to get creative and add some guides and a pulley wheel to my frame. It was inelegant, but worked fine for many years.

Answer (score 7):

Routing the cable on a front derailleur can be confusing and it's easy to insert the cable in the wrong place. An experienced mech recently told me that many front derailleurs can be installed in either a top pull or down pull configuration, and I think that's the case here. In the docs from the link provided (in the *FRONT DERAILLEUR FOR MTB/TREKKIN* section), you can see an exemple with both configurations and where the anchor is at the bottom:

[image: Top pull configuration]

[image: Down pull configuration]

Answer (score 5):

At the link you provided:

> "Top pull/down pull"

The exploded view at the same link indicates similar:

[image]

Does the part indicated look like it can be removed and rotated?

Comment: Nop, I looked at it and it is not something that can be rotated, is bolted in, not with screws but with those fixed bolts U.U

Comment: A bolt, by definition @CharlyLeyewho, can be unscrewed and is not "fixed". A rivet would be fixed, but not a bolt. Maybe you _can_ unscrew it and there's another hole for it to go into that's currently hidden by the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there used to be top pull/bottom pull and top mount/bottom mount front derailleurs.  I believe top and bottom pull were integrated together but I think top and bottom mount still exist.